# Turn off shadows cast onto Backdrop Image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

Is there a way to turn off "Shadow Catcher" for a backdrop image so no shadows are cast onto the image?

[image]

Comment: You ticked the wrong box (I rolled back your edit to my answer, because it was a comment and made no sense as an edit).

Answer (score 1):

**Cycles**

On the Object tab of the backdrop you can tick the 'Shadow' box under Ray Visibility under Cycles Settings.

**Cycles/Eevee**

A hack that works is to make the material an Emission shader. Obviously, this might introduce other problems.